# Representable bifunctors

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, adjoint-functors

Is there a notion of representability for functors in the form $F:C^{op} \times C \to Set$?

Can anyone please give me a reference?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want there to be such a notion?  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: There's, in a decent sense, only one representable bifunctor, $(X,Y)\mapsto C(X,Y)$, which contains simultaneously all the usual ones.

Comment: A functor of the form $C^{op} \times C \to Set$ is also a functor of the form $D^{op} \to Set$ for $D = C \times C^{op}$, so you do have the standard notion of representable functor available.